# Entity Framework 6, Java style enums

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

So I'm using java style enums / smart enums in my C# application.
when checking for equality in code I can do some thing like (just an example)

```
if(employee.EmployeeType == EmployeeTypes.Manager)
//...
```

EmployeeTypes.Manager is a static lookup class, so i dont need them persisted like regular entities.
How do i get EF6 to treat this class as an enum and

1. persist only the id
2. only use the id value when im using linq to query the data
   ie:

   dbcontext.Employees.Where(e=>e.EmployeeType == EmployeeTypes.Manager)

should result in

```
select ... from Employees where EmployeeType = 1
```

In NHibernate I could do this using IUserType, however I haven't found something similar in EF6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What the hell is `Java style enums`

Comment: enumerations that are more than just aliases to a number, they may contain more data and behaviour.
For example:
https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/

Comment: Written before extension methods existed.

Comment: try adding extension properties to an enum.
a very valid design pattern to address C# shortcommings with enums
regarldless, even if c# supported extension properties, good luck using EF to do anything useful with them

Comment: I assume your sample code is nothing more than a sample, if not, you're doing it wrong. EF supports inheritance & polymorphism, so you would have a Manager class and Pleb class and those classes would contain the business logic they require. Making the need for enums with behaviour non existent. The fact C# doesn't support behavious in enums is a good thing. Doesn't change the fact EF is rubbish tho.

Comment: You're right, it is a contrived sample.....
The reason i dont want to persist it is because they are lookup values that will probably never change. i could treat them as regular classes and persist, at the cost of extra db work.
Also, since working on brownfield project, moving from enum to class is way more of a refactor than i can justify at this point

.If it was inheritance i was looking for, it wouldn't have been an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101223/discussion-between-dawood-moazzem-and-phill).